# JavaFX - How to limit combobox to trigger changed event only with mouse click

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a combobox and I would like to perform something with new value after I changed the item in the combobox:

```
myComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        myCallWithNewValue(newValue);
    }
});
```

It worked well as I expected until I have another button to clear the combobox: 
`myComboBox.getItems().clear();`

When I click to this clear button, it clears the content of the combobox but also trigger the changed event which I want to avoid. How can I tell combobox to trigger the changed event only with mouse click but not with the clear button, can anyone help me please. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(newValue != null)
{
    myCallWithNewValue(newValue);
}
```

I haven't tested this answer. If null does not work, try `newValue != ""`.

Comment: definitely possible (and the best an answer can do without more context from the OP :) - but typically it's better to let the receiver (that is myCallWithNewValue) contain any exclusion logic